# Why does the logical AND operator call these two functions in this case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component class that contains two methods handleSubmit and handleReset.

```
class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // initial state
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
  }

  handleReset() {
    this.setState({
      // reset state to initial state
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // handle form submission and sending request to api endpoint
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <form className="form-horizontal col-sm-12" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <OtherFormElements />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-success"
          onClick={this.handleSubmit && this.handleReset}
        >Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

When the submit button is clicked, both functions are called. Though this is the desired result, from my own understanding of the logical AND operator, this is not supposed to be so. From my understanding, a && b will result to b if a evaluates to true. What I want to know is why are both functions called in this case?

Comment: How do you know that both functions are called?

Comment: a && b will result to b if a evaluates to true. >> Note function a needs to execute to determine if its true and then know whether to run and return function b

Comment: if this.handleSubmit is undefined, this.handleReset will be called

Comment: @FredStark No... not at all. There is no function call anywhere.

Comment: @Keith But nothing is called when passing as a prop?

Comment: Please note that they are truthy, in both cases handleSubmit exist and handleReset exist, so your onClick function will actually hold true, and doesn't do anything, your form is submitted through the handleSubmit function

Comment: @AndrewLi  Why do you think I deleted my comment?, what the OP's doing here doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `onClick={this.handleSubmit && this.handleReset}` isn’t JavaScript, and these are not function _calls_ either. Obviously React has to parse this and then evaluate it somehow. Whether it follows “standard” JavaScript logical expression rules while doing so, we can’t know. Check the documentation in that regard.

Comment: @CBroe `onClick={this.handleSubmit && this.handleReset}` gets compiled to `{..., onClick: this.handleSubmit && this.handleReset, ...}` which is clearly JavaScript without magic. What should happen is that `this.handleSubmit` evaluates to truthy, and so the entire expression should evaluate to `this.handleReset`.

Comment: @Icepickle Well, it should evaluate to `this.handleReset` as JavaScript evaluates to the right operand if left operand is truthy.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yeah, that could also be :) which would explain that both get called when submitted, but with such a statement you will never know what runs first, I guess

Comment: @Keith how do you mean?

Comment: thank's @CBroe will do that

Comment: @Madara _“gets compiled to `{..., onClick: this.handleSubmit && this.handleReset, ...}` which is clearly JavaScript without magic”_ - but those are still not function _calls_? Pretty much the same as if you did an `console.log(alert && prompt)` ... that won’t _call_ either of those methods either.

Comment: @CBroe `onClick` accepts a reference to a function, `this.handleReset` (and `this.handleSubmit`) is a reference to a function, React will bind a DOM event listener, and that will be what calls your function.

Comment: One call for onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} and another one call for this.handleReset

Comment: @Madara _“onClick accepts a reference to a function”_ - yes. But even if `foo` is a function reference, and `bar` is a function reference - that does not make `foo && bar` a function reference again, does it?

Comment: @CBroe Of course it does, `(foo && bar) === bar` (assuming both are functions), so it does resolve to a function reference.

Comment: @Madara ok, but that won’t _call_ both functions later on, if you tried to append () to this new function reference ... `(window.alert && window.prompt)()` only gives a prompt, and no alert. _So_, logical conclusion for me is that React must be parsing this, and then call both functions itself explicitly. How it interprets `&&` while doing so, is therefor up to React here, and not “default JavaScript at work” in this instance.

Comment: @CBroe No, see my answer. submitHandler is called because of the form's onSubmit, resetHandler only is from the onClick. React isn't parsing this, it's not just obvious where the second call comes from, is all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because both the Form's `onSubmit` and the button's `onClick` are called.

It's easy to deduce what would be the `onSubmit`, it's set to `this.handleSubmit`.

The button's is `this.handleSubmit && this.handleReset`, the JavaScript `&&` operator returns the **first falsey operand**, and if all of them are truthy, it retuns **the last operand**, which is `this.handleReset`.

As a result, `this.handleReset` is called when the button's `click` event is fired, followed by `this.handleSubmit` when the form's `submit` event is fired.

Comment: Ahhaaa... Thanks, I see why now

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to know is why are both functions called in this case?

Because `onClick={this.handleSubmit && this.handleReset}` evaluates to `onClick={this.handleReset}` making call to `this.handleReset` and you have `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` handler on form tag.

Therefore clicking on button calls both functions (i.e. one because of click handler and other because of form submit event).